# Cannot create DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf

I ran into problem.
I have a class and I cannot create dispatchertimer in it. But I can create Timer and both of these uses system.threading.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ProgramName
{
    
    public class TestClass : IDisposable
    {
        Timer fds; //works
        DispatcherTimer fds; //missing a using directive or an assembly reference Error
}
```

Can anyone please help me?
I tried restarting VS, rebuilding

Answer (score 0):

[DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=net-5.0) is in `System.Windows.Threading`.

You need to reference the `WindowsBase` assembly.